# What are the conditions for the POST Invitations call to return a response with a status set to "Error"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

It is said in the [Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitation?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) that a [Create Invitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) call can return a status set "Error" however it is unclear what can be the causes. Can soemone tell me more about how such a scenario can be triggered ?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the [invitation redemption flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/redemption-experience#invitation-redemption-flow) in Azure docs. The section after point 11 provides a scenario when the user/invitation status can hit an error.